# Javascript only giving whole numbers while adding up numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table and I am trying to add up a column.  It works but only shows whole numbers, not decimals.

```js
function calcProdSubTotal() {
    
    var prodSubTotal = 0;

    $(".row-total-input").each(function() {
    
        var valString = $(this).val() || 0;
        
        prodSubTotal += parseInt(valString);
                    
    });
 
    $("#product-subtotal").val(CommaFormatted(prodSubTotal));
 $("#subtotal").attr("value", prodSubTotal);
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript not Java. Please re-tag.

Comment: You may also just use type coercion by doing `prodSubTotal += +valString;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of `parseInt` - the latter produces an integer, losing whatever decimals you had in your numbers.